# Do you always need a prototype cell?

Tags: swift2, uitableview

When adding a TableView to an existing scene that uses a UIViewController class, where do you add the reuse identifier string?

Do you "have" to add a prototype cell?  That seems to be the only thing that supplies the reuse identifier field in IB.

Comment: You can supply reuse identifier in cell initializer.

Comment: 3 simple ways to create a cell. 1/ Register a nib for the identifier 2/ Register a class name (`UITableViewCell` subclass) for an identifier. Or 3/ don't register anything and in `cellForRow` use method `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. If this method returns `nil`, just create a new `UITableViewCell` instance, passing it a reuse identifier.

Answer (score 0):

***When adding a TableView to an existing scene that uses a UIViewController class, where do you add the reuse identifier string?***

If you have **static cells** then you do not need to provide a reuse identifier since the table's sections and rows are defined at comply time and are fixed: static.

If you are using **prototype cells** then you will have to define a reuse identifier, which you will do in code and Interface Builder. prototype cells are templates that are dynamically created and populated.  Most people define a static variable to hold the cell reuse identifier. It is then used in the UITableViewDataSource method [- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:) to dequeue a cell.

[image]

***Do you "have" to add a prototype cell? That seems to be the only thing that supplies the reuse identifier field in IB.***

You do not have to use a prototype cell, you could do it programmatically or use a NIB.